# Can't get download url from Firebase Storge in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Can't get download url from Firebase Storge in Android. I get:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn@
```

Instead of the url download link. My code:

```
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
@Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                uri1=uri;
                downloadURL =uri.toString();
                            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
            }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                 // Handle any errors
                             }
             });

 if(uri1==null&&downloadURL==null){
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else if(uri1==null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+downloadURL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else if(downloadURL==null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + uri1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
```

thank u

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the url, you need to attach a listener. So to solve this, please use the following code:

```
ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        String uri = uri.toString();
        Log.d("TAG", uri);
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle Errors
    }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't post just an example, you should add the exact code you are using. So please share the exact code in order to see the problem.

Comment: See here [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you don't share your code, I cannot be much of a help.

Comment: i try what u send and its show error in taskSnapshot what i need to do?

Comment: Please see my first comment.

Comment: Seeing the code above, you need to move that if statement inside the `onSuccess` method. The corresponding toast will work correctly, right?

Comment: i put the toast just to see if i get the right link. i use the link to put is in firestore.

Comment: If yiu are using those values outside will always be `null`. That's why I said to you to move them inside. Does it work when are inside?

Comment: no it still not working

Comment: what is the taskSnapshot u do in the answer (may what u answer will work)

Comment: See now with a simplified version.

Comment: I am try log.d and its not work to me at all in my android studio

Comment: Is not working? Why? What is happening? Do you have an error?

Comment: No, its just no show up on logcat, i ask my teacher and he show me how and its still not working.

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: No And more important to me to get the download link.