# error showing downloadUrl might not have been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

```
filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               final   Uri downloadUrl =taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Upload success! URL - " + downloadUrl.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

this is a snippet of my code,actually there is an error inside onSuccess(Uri uri) method which is in

> `downloadUrl.toString()`

and the error is varible `downloadUrl` might not have been initialized

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795091/cant-get-download-url-from-firebase-storge-in-android)** out.

Comment: its not working now the error is in uri portion although i have change the uri name to uri1 though its an error

Comment: any different solution