# How to place a Firebase generated url into an ImageView with Glide?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

So when I upload an image onto Firebase Storage, the `getDownloadUrl()` method generates a string such as: `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@275cc4`

Now I'm trying to place the image uploaded into an `ImageView`:

```
ImageView img;

img = v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@275cc4").into(img);
```

This doesn't seem to load the image. I tried with the full firebase url `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/.....` and this worked, but I can't seem to find a method that generates this when I upload an image?

Comment: Obviously, `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@275cc4` isn't a url!

Answer (score 3):

```
storageRef.child(path).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri.toString()).into(img);
                    }
                });
```

Hope this will help you.......Have a nice day

Comment: ahh, you saved me, trying to learn firebase from some old but good free stuff, and almost everything is different as usual :)

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you need to pass to the `load()` method the actual url of the photo. I'm affraid:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@275cc4
```

Is not a valid url for an image. So change the above url with one that is correct formated and includes: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/...`.

To verify if the url is correct, just copy and paste that url in a browser and see if it opens an image. If it doesn't open, it means that you have provided an incorrect url.

Comment: Is there a method that will get me the full `https` url? Or a way to manipulate that string into the correct one?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795091/cant-get-download-url-from-firebase-storge-in-android)** out. In this way you can get the download url.

Comment: Hi compsciman! Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?